# CPU usage of a process tree using perf?

Tags: profiling, perf

I executed the following command for getting the cpu usage

```
perf record -F 99 -p PID sleep 1
```

But I think this command is giving me the cpu usage of this process only.
If it fork any new process then the cpu usage of that process will not be included in the perf report.

Can someone suggest how can we get the cpu usage of a given PID with usage of all its successors combined ?

Also i am interested in getting the peak cpu usage at any interval.Is this also possible using perf?

Comment: You may try `-a` option of perf record to profile whole system (all pids). Are successors of your PID forked before perf was started or after it? Why do you want to monitor CPU usage with `perf` which is (medium- to high-frequency) profiling tool, not the CPU monitoring (why not use `top` or any newer flavor of `top`, some of them are capable of monitoring process trees).